# In System recovery Progress bar hasn’t moved for 2 hours

Tags: system-restore

I booted from the recovery parition (hitting F8 on when booting up and selecting Repair computer) Then selected System Image Recovery, and selected the image I made on my external HDD (using the built in windows software) about 84GB. it then went along fine, and the progress bar reached 100%, but then it went back down to 0%, and got to about 1% 2 hours ago and hasn't moved since.

What do I do? I can click Stop Restore, but it says It might make it unusable (it was unusable in the first place though, because the power cut when I was doing a standard System restore inside windows completely) but seeing as A re-imaging moves my personal files around, I don't want to find all my files deleted, and there are some very important files to me (which I thought I backed up using the System Image I am trying to restore).

Please answer quick (and don't see this as being rude please), because I need to get on my computer before tommorrow to do some work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify what you've done against this article : [Restoring a Disk Image](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1400869&seqNum=4).

If all seems correct, it might be a bad sector on the disk. You should do Full format of the disk in this case.